# Why is my cat so aggressive about feeding?

Tags: cats, feeding

I adopted two male kittens (brothers), who are about 8 months old now. They are both generally calm and I play with them pretty frequently. They also have plenty of toys. I give them wet and dry food twice a day at 6 am and 6 pm.

The problem I'm having is that one of them has become very aggressive about feeding time. Even if there is still wet and/or dry food in their bowls, he will start to meow constantly. This is fine in the evenings, but increasingly annoying in the morning. I often wake up to him meowing at the bedroom door, which is soon followed by digging and scratching. I'm worried this may cause damage.

I don't think it's because he is hungry. He's been putting on a little weight, and sometimes when I feed him, he'll take 3 bites and then go do something else.

Comment: If the meowing isn't related to the dishes being empty, why do you think it's related to feeding?  Is it possible he just wants to get into the bedroom or wants attention?

Comment: @Meg He only does it around feeding time. So he'll start at say, 5:45 AM and go until  6. He won't meow at the door at any other point of the night

Comment: @Meg And he also does it at night too, when we are out and about. If it hits 6 pm or thereabouts, he'll start meowing at me until I feed him

Comment: Seems a bit like an act of habit. He might be just getting impatient or hears noises from your room.